# Is it possible to reference an object created in a pyi file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting, pytz

I have a module that needs a type hint which already exists in a .pyi.  Is there someway I can reference that the object from said .pyi?

[types-pytz](https://pypi.org/project/types-pytz/) module has a typeshed hint called `_UTCclass` that I would like to use to annotate one of my functions.

I would normally just reference the actual class definition but in this case the `pytz` package makes that [impossible](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/bd7b5288d7143fba7c5655ae8a81c0eb1ea9b1d7/src/pytz/__init__.py#L263).

```py
# from pytz.__init__.py
UTC = utc = UTC()
```

Here is what happens when I try to use `pytz.UTC` as an annotation:

```py
def myfunc() -> Union[StaticTzInfo, DstTzInfo, pytz.UTC]:
   ...
```

`TypeError: Union[arg, ...]: each arg must be a type. Got <UTC>.`

Is there another way to tackle this without having to recreate `_UTCclass` in my code?

Comment: since the UTC class is overwritten by an instance of it, you'll have to infer the type (i.e. the class of the instance), e.g. by using `pytz.UTC.__class__`

Comment: Oh right! That works as a nice solution to referencing the uninstantiated class. While that solves my overall problem I'm still curious, from an academic standpoint, if it's possible to reference objects within the pyi.  My hunch says no....

Comment: mypy type checker cannot identify `pytz.UTC.__class__` it shows up as not defined.